# Subtracting a context-free language from a regular language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have the language
$L=\{a, bb\}^*-\{a^ib^i|i\geq1\}$ and I have to show that $L$ is context-free.

The first language is Regular, if I'm not mistaken, and the second is a well known context-free language.

I guess I have to prove the hypothesis using the closure properties (a regular language intersected with a context-free is a context-free) but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Your guess is right, but there is still some work to do. Your language is the intersection of the regular language $\{a,bb\}^*$ and of the complement $C$ of the language $\{a^nb^n \mid n > 0\}$. You probably know that the intersection of a regular language with a context-free language is context-free. The problem is now to prove that $C$ is context-free, since in general, the complement of a context-free language is not context-free.

See the question [How to create a grammar for complement of $a^nb^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550756/how-to-create-a-grammar-for-complement-of-anbn) if you don't find the solution yourself.

Comment: I discarted the idea of finding the complement of the context-free language (since it's not closed), didn't think about finding the complement "by hand" and proving it's context-free too! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I just thought that the language $a^nb^n$ is deterministic context free and the DCF class of languages is closed under complement. So there is no need to build the complement grammar to show that it's context free.

Comment: If you know about deterministic context free languages, yes, it is the shortest way.