# Prove/disprove that language of complement of $L=\{a^mb^n|m\neq n \space, m,n\geq1\}$ is context free over alphabet $\{a,b\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma

> Prove/disprove that language of complement of $L=\{a^mb^n|m\neq n \space, m,n\geq1\}$ is context free over alphabet $\{a,b\}$?

---

My attempt :

Using pumping lemma [$L=\{a^mb^n|m\neq n \space, m,n\geq1\}$ is not regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480430/show-0m1n-m-neq-n-is-not-regular), But it is context free language.

Complement of $L$,

$\overline{L}=\Sigma^*-L$, it should be context free language as [complement of ${a^nb^n}$ is also context free language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550756/how-to-create-a-grammar-for-complement-of-anbn).

> > Can you explain in formal way, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that $\overline L$ is context-free, but that does not help you because **the context-free languages are not closed under complement**.

So you need a different start.

**Hint:** Write $L$ as $\{a^mb^n\mid 1\le m<n\} \cup \{a^mb^n\mid 1\le n<m\}$.